# In Cpp for is not working properly from the function

Tags: c++, oop

I need to do this exercise, with struct and include the function in the struct to do the calculations, but for some reason, it's not working.
I recommended you to check the image for a better idea.
[image: Exercice]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Alfa{
    double h,x,n,a;
    void shuma(){
        cout << "enter n: "; cin >> n;
        cout << "enter a: "; cin >> a;
        for (int i = 1; i >= n; i++){
            x = 2 * i + a;
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    Alfa alf;
    alf.shuma();
        alf.h = (alf.x / 2) + 3;

    cout <<  alf.h;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's not C code (which it isn't), then you shouldn't include the C tag. Please make an edit that removes it.

Comment: Why don't you follow the image you provide? `alf.h = (alf.x / 2) + 3` and you should accumulate in `x` with `+=` starting from `0`.

Comment: the condition in for loop `i >= n` is not correct, it will be true only if `n` is **0, 1 or a negative number**

Comment: `x = 2 * i + a;` inside the loop makes `x` only keep the value of the last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following the formula in the image. Use this instead:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++) {
    if (i != 4) {
        sum += 2 * i + a;
    }
}
h = x / 2 + 3 * sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 1; i >= n; i++)` means `i` initiated to 1, while `i>=n` do the loop, then inc `i`. So when `n` is bigger then 1, it will never enter the loop. Maybe you want `for (int i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)` ?